# Python making list

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, iteration

I'm a super n00b in python.
I have been struggling with finding proper solution.
Here is the list, `L = [0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 12, 13, 14, 0, 0, 0, 18, 19, 20]`, and each of the items refers to location in the list.

I wanted to make list from the upper list, showing smaller lists inside the list, and each of the elements represents starting location of the series, end of the series and number of elements. This should be `[[3, 6, 4], [11, 14, 4], [18, 20, 3]]`. How could I write code for this? Following is what I have done so far.

```
target = []
target.append([])
target.append([])
target.append([])

L = [0,0,0,0,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,0,0,13,14,15,0,0,0,19,20,21]

for i in L :
    if i == 0 :
        L.remove(i)
        continue
    elif i != 0 :
        startpoint = i
        i = i * i
        while i != 0 :
            i += 1
            continue
        else :
            j = i
            endpoint = i - 1
            break
    target[0].append(startpoint)
    target[1].append(endpoint)
    target[2].append(j)
```

Comment: At the start you create three empty lists inside `target`, and in the loop you append `startpoint` to the first, `endpoint` to the second, and `j` to the third. However, in your example output, those three variables are each grouped into one list.

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of the statement `i = i*i`?

Comment: Also, with the statement `i += 1`, you probably intend to advance to the next index in the list, but `i` is not an index but a value from the list (as specified by `for i in L`).

Comment: I noticed that each of the numbers in the list is representing two pieces of data at once:  the index of that entry and whether or not that entry is "interesting" (i.e. `a` is interesting if `a != 0`). However the first entry of the list will always be `0`, no matter whether it is "interesting" or not! This seems like a potential bug. It might be better to store a list of booleans and use `enumerate(L)` to get the index information when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your code one mistake is that in following `while` :

```
while i != 0 :
        i += 1
```

You must not increase `i` you need to increase the index of elements not itself!then continue to appending when you find a none zero element!

But as a more pythonic way You can use `itertools.groupby` with a list comprehension :

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [[i[0],i[-1],len(i)] for i in [list(g) for _,g in groupby(L,key=lambda x:x!=0)]if i[0]!=0]
[[3, 6, 4], [11, 14, 4], [18, 20, 3]]
```

*Note* that `groupby` returns the grouped elements as a generator (`g`) and when you want to loop over it you dont need to convert it to `list` but in this case as we need the length we must convert to `list` till we can use `len` function.

Comment: Thanks for your advice,  and it works! I knew I had to use groupby function, but eventhough I read documentation about it several times, I completely don't understand how to use it. Now I can research by my self about it. Thanks!

Comment: @winterfield Welcome, `groupby` returns the grouped elements as a generator (`g`) and when you want to loop over it you dont need to convert to `list` but in this case as we need the length we must convert to `list` till we can use `len` function

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version based on your attempt:

```
L=[0,0,0,3,4,5,6,0,0,0,0,11,12,13,14,0,0,0,18,19,20]

target = []

i = 0
while i < len(L):
  if L[i] == 0 :
    i += 1
    continue
  start = i
  while i < len(L) and L[i] != 0:
    i += 1
  target.append((L[start],L[i-1],i-start))
```

Comment: Thank you! this is a more closer way for what  I intended to do.